# Access phpunit inside my project folder. phpunit: command not found

Tags: php, phpunit

I have installed phpunit by opening gitbash of my windows system and running the following command.

```
composer require --dev phpunit/phpunit ^9
```

It installed successfully and when I type following command

```
./vendor/bin/phpunit --version
```

it returns **PHPUnit 9.5.21** . I think phpunit is installed in this location

**C:\Users\ERIKSON\vendor\phpunit**

Now I have a project in my xampp folder

**C:\xampp\htdocs\erikson-project\wp-content\plugins\youtube-plugin**

when I open GitBash in this project location and run the command PHPUnit it says

> ***bash: phpunit: command not found***

. How can I solve this ? Please help.

I have composer.json file inside youtube-plugin folder and the code is
**C:\xampp\htdocs\erikson-project\wp-content\plugins\youtube-plugin\composer.json**

```
{
    "require-dev": {
        "phpunit/phpunit": "9.5"
    }
}
```

Do I need to add anything in my windows system environment variable?

Comment: I would suggest you to boot your project from a docker container. So you have your project and phpunit in the same working directory. So you don't have to think about configure/link environment variables.

Comment: Did you run `composer install --dev` inside the `youtube-plugin` folder?